# How to change picker Title font size in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have used picker control in my app and when I'm running on iOS 11 pro device it's Title text font size shows big than it's actual font size

```
<CustomControl:BindablePicker x:Name="pick"
              Font="lato-regular" 
              FontSize="12" 
              Title="{Binding Placeholder}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Season}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              BorderWidth="1" />
```

> iOS Renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
    var view = (BindablePicker)Element;
    if (view != null && Control != null)
    {
        SetFont(view);
    }
}

void SetFont(BindablePicker view)
{
     var fontsize = view.FontSize;
     var font = UIKit.UIFont.FromName("lato-regular", (System.nfloat)fontsize);
     if (font != null)
     {
         Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((System.nfloat)fontsize);
         Control.Font = font;
     }
}
```

**Output on iOS:**

[image]

Comment: Hi , it seems not work in current version of VS . What's the version of VS and iOS tested in project ?

Comment: VS 2019 Version 8.4.5 (build 19), Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.10.0.17.  I have tried your code it's not working @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for replying , I also reproduced it in the latest version of VS . However , I have found a solution to solve that , will update in answer .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  I'm excited for the solution as i have tried different ways but not worked, waiting for your answer please put it asap.

Comment: Yeah , answer has been updated , you can have a look . :-）

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my local site , even the latest version of VS , it also not works .

However , if not mind not using **UIFont.FromName**, there is a **Solution** to solve that .

You can replace it with `Control.Font.WithSize(xxx)`; or `UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(xxx)` to change the font size .

Code as follow :

```
void SetFont(BindablePicker view)
{
    var fontsize = view.FontSize;
    Control.Font = Control.Font.WithSize((System.nfloat)fontsize);
     // or
    //Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((System.nfloat)fontsize);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it's also not working :( @JuniorJiand-MSFT

Comment: @Divyesh_008 This is my sample link , you can test in your local site . If also not works , you need to udpate the version of VS to the latest version `8.6.2` .https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fd2phs5j2frxqx/AppFormsPicker.rar?dl=0

Comment: Your sample is working fine, so I don't think that I have to update vs

Comment: @Divyesh_008 Okey , that should be other reasons . You can check somewhere whether affect it .

Comment: @Divyesh_008 Have you solved that ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark or vote up it when you have time :-)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSTF thanks a lot for your replay and solution but it did not worked for me my issue is still same, that's why I have not up vote it yet

Comment: @Divyesh_008 Okey . If possible you can share a new created sample project here , I will check that .